# android gridview with contents inflated from xml has each row taking entire screen

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a `Gridview` in Android where each element is inflated from xml and contains a `LinearLayout` holding an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. The `GridView` uses a custom Adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`. What I see is that each row rather than being just high enough to hold the largest element, is as tall as the screen.

Here is the relevant code:

The gridview's xml:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ConSoul"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="160dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

The element's xml (thumbnail.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="120dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/theme"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The adapter `getView` method (`mContext` is an instance variable the adapter is created from, screens is a `Bitmap[]` and names is a `String[]`):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View thumbView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        thumbView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, null);
    } else {
        thumbView = convertView;
    }
    ((ImageView)thumbView.findViewById(R.id.screen)).setImageBitmap(screens[position]);
    ((TextView)thumbView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(names[position]);
    return thumbView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout height of "wrap_content" travels through your `LinearLayout` and your `ImageView`. The `ImageView` `ScaleType` is set to "fitEnd" which causes alignment [to the right and bottom edges of dst](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#END).

This bottom alignment is causing your Grid item layout to take up as much room as possible; the entire screen height. Change to one of the other `ScaleType` values such as "fitStart" or "fitCenter" and your `GridView` should be ok.

Comment: Interesting. The reason I chose the fitEnd was because I want the text to be immediately below the images, and the images are wider than they are tall and if they are centered there tends to be a gap before the text.

Comment: If you want to use "fitEnd", you may have to specify height as well as width (i.e. "120dp").

Comment: I tried setting the linearlayout to 120dp by 80dp but it looked the same, still each row is 1 screen height high :-(

Comment: I had to set an explicit width on the linearlayout, imageview, textview, all equal to the gridview column width, as well as an explicit height for the imageview and the linearlayout, then it works.  You answer pointed me in the right direction so I've marked it as correct.